# How to inject a .dll file dynamically into a program at runtime using the dependency injection principle in CPP?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, dll, architecture

## Problem

I read about .dll file in Learn Microsoft ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/linking-an-executable-to-a-dll?view=msvc-170)) that there're two way to link a .dll file, and I want to **explicit linking** my .dll to my `cpp` application. Assume that I am writing a console application.

## For basic

I'm writing a program to calculate area and perimeter for some type of shapes. It may be rectangle, circle, ellipse, etc. My current application can calculate area and perimeter for a rectangle and circle. I have built it into an `app.exe` file.

How can I write an `ellipse.dll` file containing `class Ellipse` which inherits from `class IShape` in `app.exe` so the `app.exe` can automatically import `class Ellipse` to calculate area and perimeter for Ellipse without rebuilding the application and modifying source code?

## More clearly

- This application cannot calculate area and perimeter of ellipse

```
Application
|--- app.exe
```

- This application can calculate area and perimeter of ellipse

```
Application
|--- app.exe
|--- ellipse.dll
```

## About source code

- I think the flow of recognize DLL file as below.

```
1. Load all the name of DLL files in main executable folder (folder Application from above example).
2. Load all DLL files to get the class, function from DLL file.
3. Create the instance of concrete class that inherits from IShape (a Shape interface).
```

But I don't know the concept of load DLL file and write class DLL file in `CPP`.

- I used dependency injection principle for all my current shape. I also use Factory pattern for parser data from users and create instance of shape.

(My sincere apologies for any grammatical errors or contextual inaccuracies in my use of my English. Thank you for your understanding.)

Answer (score 0):

I followed the tutorial [here](https://youtu.be/7iYhuqEbJZs).

Writing a DLL for Eclipse class:

`EclipseDLL.h`:

```
#ifdef ECLIPSEDLL_EXPORTS
#define ECLIPSEDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define ECLIPSEDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include "IShape.h"

// This class is exported from the DLL
class ECLIPSEDLL_API Eclipse: public IShape {
public:
    Eclipse(const float&, const float&);
    float perimeter() override;
    float area() override;
private:
    float _a;
    float _b;
};

extern "C" ECLIPSEDLL_API IShape* createEclipse(const float&, const float&);
```

`EclipseDLL.cpp`:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "framework.h"
#include "EclipseDLL.h"

Eclipse::Eclipse(const float& a, const float&b)
{
    _a = a;
    _b = b;
}

float Eclipse::perimeter()
{
    //TODO
}

float Eclipse::area()
{
    //TODO
}

IShape* createEclipse(const float& a, const float&b)
{
    return new Eclipse(a, b);
}
```

Using:

```
// Load DLL

string libPath = "EclipseDLL.dll"; // From your DLL build
HMODULE hLib = nullptr;
hLib = LoadLibrary(CA2W(libPath.c_str())); // CA2W converts string/const char* to wchar
if (hLib) {
    IShape* (*func) (const float&, const float&); // Declare a function pointer to retrieve from DLL
    func = (IShape* (*)(const float&, const float&)) GetProcAddress(hLib, ("createEclipse").c_str());

    Factory::addNewProduct("Eclipse", func);

    if (hLib && func) {
        cout << "loaded successfully\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "loaded failed\n";
    }

}

// Testing

IShape *test = nullptr;
test = Fatory:create("Eclipse");
if (test) {
    cout<<test->perimeter()<<"-"<<test->area()<<"\n";
}
else {
    cout<<"class not found\n";
}

if (hLib) {
    FreeLibrary(hLib);
}

delete test;
```

I wrote this answer on notepad, there might be some syntax errors. You can test a similar implementation [here](https://github.com/lhson0606/personal-randomStuff.git).